# Making a column with differences between 2 other column

Tags: python, pandas

I already started a similar topick, but few essential novelties are brought in. We have two columns: "333, 444, 555", and "333A, 444, 555B", and we need to get a column shewing "A, n/a, B", i.e. difference in values between the two.

```
one= ''
for h in str(column1):
    if h not in str(column2):
        one += h
```

whence we get a string of differences. But is there are way to delimit the outcome and eventually place it at corresponding rows? Making

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 333 | 333A | A |
| 444 | 444 | n/a |
| 555 | 555B | B |

? Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to have '777' and '787C' on the same row? or the first column is the prefix of the second one?

Comment: hi! yes the column were compare, have values on samr row, as in mz example: 333 and 333A belong to one row.

Comment: The output for  '777' and '787C' is '8C'?

Comment: yes, that is the required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `difflib`:

```
from difflib import ndiff

diff = lambda x: ''.join(c[-1] for c in ndiff(x['Col1'], x['Col2']) if c[0] == '+')
df['Col3'] = df.astype({'Col1': str, 'Col2': str}).apply(diff, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
   Col1  Col2 Col3
0   333  333A    A
1   444   444     
2   555  555B    B
3   777  787C   8C
```

Using `astype({'Col1': str, 'Col2': str})` is not mandatory if you already have strings.

**Update**

Try this version:

```
def diff(x):
    s1 = str(x['Col1'])
    s2 = str(x['Col2'])
    l = [c[-1] for c in ndiff(s1, s2) if c[0] == '+']
    return ''.join(l)

df['Col3'] = df.apply(diff, axis=1)
```

Explanation:

Suppose the strings `s1 = '567'` and `s2 = '597C'`. The expected result is '9C'.

```
# Without a comprehension
for c in ndiff(s1, s2):
    print(c)

# Output
  5  # character in both strings
+ 6  # character in s1 only
+ 9  # character in s2 only
  7  # character in both strings
+ C  # character in s2 only
```

- `c[0]` is the first character (the sign '+' or '-' or ' ')
- `c[-1]` is the last character (the current letter)

So with the comprehension, we want to extract the current character `c[-1]` only if the sign `c[0]` is `'+'`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used `astype` to ensure the two columns have string dtype